# How do I only copy over until a certain column in a csv file into a sqlite database table?

Tags: python, sqlite, csv

```
import sqlite3
import csv

con = sqlite3.connect("covid_student.db")
cur = con.cursor()

with open ('covid.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    columns = next(reader) 
    query = 'insert into Patient({0}) values ({1})'
    query = query.format(','.join(columns), ','.join('?' * len(columns)))
    cursor = con.cursor()
    for data in reader:
        cursor.execute(query, data)
    cursor.commit()

con.commit()
con.close()
```

This is the code I have got so far. How can I improve it to achieve what I need.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. To use the site best, you might want to consider reading: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code by using [executemany()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html) function of the sqlite3 library, which will do a bulk insert in one go. Read the column names into a list and the rest of the data into another, then do a bulk insert:

```
with open('covid.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    columns = next(reader)
    query = "INSERT INTO Patient({0}) VALUES ({1})".format(','.join(columns), ','.join(['?'] * len(columns)))
    rest = [row for row in reader]
    cursor.executemany(query, rest)
```